# TSQL, Fill and remove table rows, purpose of calculating a consistent average per day

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, average

So I have intra day data that comes in pretty much randomly during the day 9-17.
I want to calculate a consistent average for each day, by basically aggregating the intra day data to only hourly data, and always the same amount per day (9) so when I calculate the average I don't get weird results just because one day we had lots of data etc.

Say that the values are "current price", so if I have 2 data points one day, say that the first is 0.5 at 09:00 and the second is 0.9 at 16:01, then I wouldn't want (0.5+0.9)/2 obviously, but (9*0.5+0.9)/9

Example:

Current table:

```
DateIntra           DateHour    Type    Value
2015-09-25 09:34    9           A       0.7
2015-09-25 09:35    9           A       0.6
2015-09-25 10:59    10          A       0.5
2015-09-25 16:59    16          A       0.4
2015-09-25 10:17    10          B       1.2
2015-09-25 11:19    11          B       1.7
2015-09-26 15:34    15          A       0.5
2015-09-26 15:35    15          A       0.6
```

Result:

Notice that the first value is 0.7.
Logic: When hours need to be filled after the current hour, use the first value for the current hour and the last value to fill the hours to come.

```
Date                DateHour    Type    Value
2015-09-25          9           A       0.7
2015-09-25          10          A       0.5
2015-09-25          11          A       0.5
2015-09-25          12          A       0.5
2015-09-25          13          A       0.5
2015-09-25          14          A       0.5
2015-09-25          15          A       0.5
2015-09-25          16          A       0.4
2015-09-25          17          A       0.4
2015-09-25          9           B       1.2
2015-09-25          10          B       1.2
2015-09-25          11          B       1.7
2015-09-25          12          B       1.7
2015-09-25          13          B       1.7
2015-09-25          14          B       1.7
2015-09-25          15          B       1.7
2015-09-25          16          B       1.7
2015-09-25          17          B       1.7
2015-09-26          9           A       0.5
2015-09-26          10          A       0.5
2015-09-26          11          A       0.5
2015-09-26          12          A       0.5
2015-09-26          13          A       0.5
2015-09-26          14          A       0.5
2015-09-26          15          A       0.6
2015-09-26          16          A       0.6
2015-09-26          17          A       0.6
```

Any idea how I could do this efficiently?
My first thought, as a Java programmer, was to do a WHILE loop, but I try to avoid that in SQL for performance reasons. But if that's the best way to go, then I'm open for it of course.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "always the same amount per day (10)". if you use (9*0.5+0.9)/10 you are heavily weighing your daily averages by the first data point by a random amount (based on how many data points you get), and what if you get more than 10?

Comment: I can,t see any logic in your data : 2015-09-25 - 16 h is 0.4 but (0.6 * 2 + 0.5 * 6 + 0.4 * 2) = 0.5

Comment: Yes, I want to heavily weight the daily averages by the first data point in that case. You can view it as a price. If something cost 10 dollars the whole day except for the last hour, I want that to be reflected in the average.

Comment: If I get more than 10 data points, I want to use the last one in that hour if I need to expand for hours after that, and the first one in that hour to potentially fill out the hours before that (if it was the first data point)

Comment: Why is there no data point in your result for hour 17 on 9/25... is that a mistake or intended?

Comment: Mistake, my bad! Should be a hour 17 there. Sorry.

Comment: why the 1st row does not seem to be user (0.7). do you do an average of 0.7 and 0.6 for row 1 and 2? How do you distinguish the 1st 3 and last 2 rows? They have the same date and type.

Comment: Looking at hours 9 through 17 is a nine hour spread, not a ten hour spread.  Are you sure you want to divide by 10?  And you want each hour weighted the same?

Comment: T logic is: If hours need to be filled in after the current hour, use the first value for the current hour and use the last value for the current hour to fill the coming hours. So you are right, the first should be 0.7

Comment: Oh god, I should have looked through my text, yes you are of course right :) I should divide it by 9. Yep, each hour is weighted the same.

Comment: Sorry everyone for having such an incomplete logic description. I've edited the question now so it's more correct.

Comment: Why now are hours 11-15 on 9/25 not 0.5?

Comment: Okay each hour is weighted the same, hours with no data take on the last value from the previous hour, and initial hours with no data take on the first value for the day.

Comment: Brian you are right, I'm so sorry for all the errors...

Comment: Nope, there can be several types per day. You can see it as products. Several products have different costs per day.

Comment: you don't want to avg values from the same hour?  so your 2nd price for product A, 0.6, isn't lost?  If there hadn't been a price at hr. 10, then it would have been used, but I would think you'd want product A's 9:00 price to be 0.65 instead of 0.7

Comment: That would of course be optimal, but it's really not necessary. I make such big assumptions by flattening out the prices anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about using CTE's like this:

**Edited To Correctly calculate average**
1.) Ensure that I count the hour from 17-18
2.) Divide by the sum of the hours rather than COUNT(*)
3.) Exclude rows that have the same hour as the previous row and the next row is only one hour in advance,
4.) now uses last value in an hour for subsequent values

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1607e/11)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ValueLog
(
    DateIntra DATETIME,
    [Type] VARCHAR(10),
    [Value] float
)

INSERT INTO ValueLog
VALUES
('2015-09-25 09:34', 'A', 0.7),
('2015-09-25 09:35', 'A', 0.6),
('2015-09-25 10:59', 'A', 0.5),
('2015-09-25 16:59', 'A', 0.4),
('2015-09-25 10:17', 'B', 1.2),
('2015-09-25 11:19', 'B', 1.7),
('2015-09-26 15:34', 'A', 0.5),
('2015-09-26 15:35', 'A', 0.6)
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT DateIntra, CAST(DateIntra As Date) AS [Date], DATEPART(hour,DateIntra) As DateHour, [Type], [Value], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Type], CAST(DateIntra As Date), DATEPART(hour,DateIntra) ORDER BY DateIntra) AS RN1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Type], CAST(DateIntra As Date) ORDER BY DateIntra) AS RN2
    FROM ValueLog
),
ValueOrder
As
(
    SELECT DateIntra, CAST(DateIntra As Date) As [Date], DateHour, [Type], [Value], RN1, RN2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION  BY C1.[Date], C1.[Type] ORDER BY C1.DateINtra) RN
    FROM CTE C1
    WHERE RN1 = 1 OR (RN1 > 1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CTE C2 WHERE C1.[Date] = C2.[Date] AND C1.[Type] = C2.[Type] AND C2.RN2 > C1.RN2))
),
NumHours
AS
(
    SELECT V1.DateIntra, V1.DateHour, V1.[Type], 
           COALESCE(V2.DateHour, 18) - (CASE WHEN V1.RN = 1 THEN 9 ELSE V1.DateHour END) as numHours, V1.[Value], V1.[Date], V1.RN
    FROM ValueOrder V1
    LEFT JOIN ValueOrder V2
        ON V1.[Type] = V2.[Type] AND V1.[Date] = V2.[Date] AND V2.RN = V1.RN + 1
)
SELECT [Type], [Date], SUM(numHours * Value) / SUM(numHours) As Average
FROM NumHours
GROUP BY [Type], [Date]
ORDER BY [Type], [Date]
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1607e/11/0)**:

```
| Type |       Date |            Average |
|------|------------|--------------------|
|    A | 2015-09-25 |                0.5 |
|    A | 2015-09-26 | 0.5333333333333333 |
|    B | 2015-09-25 |  1.588888888888889 |
```

Comment: Great, very elegant! Will be trying this one when I get home aswell! Big thanks. I've never really used this site much before, but with responses like this I almost expect to abuse it, haha!

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand something in the question. How 2015-09-25 / A with a range of value from 0.4 to 0.7 could have an average value of 1.36... ? Same for the other 2 sample dates.

Comment: Yeah, that's wrong. Gonna check out what he did to get those averages.

Comment: @user1867348 updated based upon the feedbacl from Julien Vavasseur. Now should correctly calculate average

Comment: @JulienVavasseur thanks for your feedback, I've updated the question to correctly calculate the value

Comment: Very nice, thanks. It's incredible fast aswell, which is awesome.

Comment: I think 25/09/2015 - B should be 1,588888889 and 26/09/2015 - A should be 0,522222222 according to its logic, the sample and all the updates.

Comment: Yeah there's still some potentially heavy assumptions in your query. For example It doesn't distribute the rates into 9 hour days every day, like the solution by Julien does.

Comment: @JulienVavasseur you are quite right on your comments, i'd missed that. See updated answer now uses last value for subsequent filled in hours and excludes the value for A where it is the second value in the hour but there is an immediate value in the next hour - A, 9 on the 25th

Answer (score 0):

This query works has expected. You can use it to compute the average.
It uses the first available value to fill previous gaps and the last available value to fell following gaps. 
First available value is used when hours match.

- Data

  ```
  create table yourData(DateIntra datetime2, DateHour int, Type char(1), Value numeric(10,2))
  insert into yourData(DateIntra, DateHour, Type, Value) values
  ('2015-09-25 09:34', 9, 'A', 0.7)
  , ('2015-09-25 09:35', 9, 'A', 0.6)
  , ('2015-09-25 10:59', 10, 'A', 0.5)
  , ('2015-09-25 16:59', 16, 'A', 0.4)
  , ('2015-09-25 10:17', 10, 'B', 1.2)
  , ('2015-09-25 11:19', 11, 'B', 1.7)
  , ('2015-09-26 15:34', 15, 'A', 0.5)
  , ('2015-09-26 15:35', 15, 'A', 0.6);
  ```
- Query

  ```
  with hours(DateIntra, DateHour, Type) as(
      Select distinct DateIntra = cast(DateIntra as date), n, Type From yourData
      Cross Join (values(9), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17)) as h(n)
  ), data as (
      Select DateIntra = cast(DateIntra as date), DateHour, Type, Value
          , up = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Type, cast(DateIntra as date), DateHour Order by DateIntra)
          , down = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Type, cast(DateIntra as date), DateHour Order by DateIntra desc)
          , rn1 = DENSE_RANK() over(partition by Type, cast(DateIntra as date) Order by DateHour)
          , rn2 = DENSE_RANK() over(partition by Type, cast(DateIntra as date) Order by DateHour desc)
      From yourData d
  )
      Select h.DateIntra, h.DateHour, h.Type, d1.Value From hours h
      Inner Join data d1 On d1.DateIntra = h.DateIntra and d1.DateHour = h.DateHour and d1.Type = h.Type and d1.up = 1
  Union All
      Select h.DateIntra, h.DateHour, h.Type, d1.Value From data d1
      Inner Join data d2 on d1.DateIntra = d2.DateIntra and d2.DateHour > d1.DateHour and d1.Type = d2.Type and d1.rn1 = d2.rn1-1 and d1.down = 1
      Inner Join hours h on d1.DateIntra = h.DateIntra and h.DateHour > d1.DateHour and h.DateHour < d2.DateHour and d1.Type = h.Type
  Union All 
      Select h.DateIntra, h.DateHour, h.Type, d1.Value From data d1 
      Inner Join hours h on d1.DateIntra = h.DateIntra and d1.DateHour > h.DateHour and d1.Type = h.Type
      Where d1.rn1 = 1 and d1.up = 1 and d1.DateHour > 9
  Union All 
      Select h.DateIntra, h.DateHour, h.Type, d1.Value From data d1 
      Inner Join hours h on d1.DateIntra = h.DateIntra and d1.DateHour < h.DateHour and d1.Type = h.Type
      Where d1.rn2 = 1 and d1.down = 1 and d1.DateHour < 17
  Order By h.DateIntra, h.Type, h.DateHour
  ```
- Ouput

  ```
  DateIntra  | DateHour | Type | Value
  2015-09-25 | 9        | A    | 0.70
  2015-09-25 | 10       | A    | 0.50
  2015-09-25 | 11       | A    | 0.50
  2015-09-25 | 12       | A    | 0.50
  2015-09-25 | 13       | A    | 0.50
  2015-09-25 | 14       | A    | 0.50
  2015-09-25 | 15       | A    | 0.50
  2015-09-25 | 16       | A    | 0.40
  2015-09-25 | 17       | A    | 0.40
  2015-09-25 | 9        | B    | 1.20
  2015-09-25 | 10       | B    | 1.20
  2015-09-25 | 11       | B    | 1.70
  2015-09-25 | 12       | B    | 1.70
  2015-09-25 | 13       | B    | 1.70
  2015-09-25 | 14       | B    | 1.70
  2015-09-25 | 15       | B    | 1.70
  2015-09-25 | 16       | B    | 1.70
  2015-09-25 | 17       | B    | 1.70
  2015-09-26 | 9        | A    | 0.50
  2015-09-26 | 10       | A    | 0.50
  2015-09-26 | 11       | A    | 0.50
  2015-09-26 | 12       | A    | 0.50
  2015-09-26 | 13       | A    | 0.50
  2015-09-26 | 14       | A    | 0.50
  2015-09-26 | 15       | A    | 0.50
  2015-09-26 | 16       | A    | 0.60
  2015-09-26 | 17       | A    | 0.60
  ```

In you output, you put 0.6 but I think it should be 0.5 for `2015-09-26 15`. This value come from `2015-09-26 15:35` which is the last value for 15:

```
    2015-09-26 | 15       | A    | 0.50
```

If you wrap the 4 `Select`s and the `Union All` in a subquery with `Group By DateIntra, Type` and `AVG`, the average is:

```
DateIntra   Type Average
2015-09-25  A    0.500000
2015-09-26  A    0.522222
2015-09-25  B    1.588888
```

Comment: That's awesome! Will try it when I get home, but seems great. Thanks so much! You saved my weekend.

Comment: does it give the expected output?